Issue with Next.js: Cached Data Not Updating on Vercel Deployment
I'm encountering a perplexing issue with my Next.js admin panel, specifically regarding product management. In my implementation, I have functionalities to add and delete products, utilizing server actions and revalidating path to ensure the page reflects the changes promptly.
Here's the problem: While everything functions seamlessly in my development environment and even after building, the deployed version on Vercel exhibits unexpected behavior. When I add a product, it appears successfully, but upon navigating away from the products route and returning, the previously loaded cache is displayed instead of the updated data.
I've ensured that the revalidation mechanisms are correctly implemented and functional, yet the problem persists. Any insights or suggestions on how to tackle this caching anomaly in the Vercel deployment would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance for your assistance!
**Page.jsx code: (ALL Products Listing)
import BreadCrumb from "@/components/dashboard/breadcrumb";

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button";
import { TiPlus } from "react-icons/ti";
import { Separator } from "@/components/ui/separator";
import { DataTable } from "@/components/dashboard/marketplace/data-table";
import { columns } from "@/components/dashboard/marketplace/columns";
import Link from "next/link";

import {
  AddProduct,
  GetAllProducts,
  updateAllProducts,
} from "@/server-actions/products";

const breadcrumbItems = [
  { title: "MarketPlace", link: "/dashboard/marketplace" },
];

export default async function Marketplace() {
  const products = await GetAllProducts();

  return (
    <div className="p-4 md:p-8 pt-6">
      <div className="flex justify-between items-center space-y-4  ">
        <BreadCrumb items={breadcrumbItems} />
        <Link href="/dashboard/marketplace/new">
          <Button className="!mt-0">
            <TiPlus className="mr-2" />
            Add new
          </Button>
        </Link>
      </div>
      <Separator className="my-6" />
      <DataTable searchKey="name" columns={columns} data={products} />
    </div>
  );
}


The server actions
export const addAProduct = async function (formData) {
  // Extract necessary data from formData
  const { name, description, brand, price, quantity, category } =
    Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());

  const weight = formData.get("shippingInfo.weight");
  const weightUnit = formData.get("shippingInfo.weightUnit");

  //console.log(shippingweight);
  // Create product object
  const product = new Product({
    name,
    description,
    brand,
    price,
    quantity,
    shippingInfo: weight ? { weight, weightUnit } : null,
    category,
  });

  try {
    const savedProduct = await product.save();
    console.log("Product Saved!", savedProduct);
  } catch (error) {
    // Handle error
    console.error("Error saving product:", error);
  }
  revalidateTag("products");
  redirect("/dashboard/marketplace");
};

export const GetAllProducts = unstable_cache(
  async () => {
    try {
      const products = await Product.find();
      if (!products) {
        return { error: "No Products found!" };
      }
      return products;
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return { error: "Database Error!" };
    }
  },
  ["products"],
  {
    tags: ["products"],
  }
);

Verified the implementation of revalidation mechanisms to ensure they are correctly set up.
Tested the functionality in local development and after building, where it works without issues.
I expected that upon adding a product in the Next.js admin panel, the page would promptly reflect the changes, both in local development and after deployment on Vercel.
